# Installing applications that are OS dependent

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I am working at pc repair shop, and building automated installations with cmd scripting for maximum efficiency

I am stuck with applications that are OS dependent (Net framework for windows 8 and windows 10)

Does anybody knows a cmd command (or script) for checking if os is windows 8 or windows 10, than installing apps for that os?

Comment: This might help: https://www.bing.com/search?q=determine+os+powershell&FORM=AWRE

Comment: check this one, a batch file that does exactly what you want: https://helloacm.com/windows-batch-script-to-detect-windows-version/

Comment: I dont know why this script dosnt work https://helloacm.com/windows-batch-script-to-detect-windows-version/ getting error that process cannot access file, and acting strangely

Comment: I find error in script above that arana posted. In script have errorlevel but need to be %errorlevel%. But still cant get to work. It's getting error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, with help of arana
[Link](https://helloacm.com/windows-batch-script-to-detect-windows-version/)

In this link you can see script for detecting windows operating system, but have errors, e.g. errorlevel instead %errorlevel% and if function eqaul = instead ==

```
echo off
ver | findstr "5.1" > nul
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto next0
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto xp

:next0
ver | findstr "6.0" > nul
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto next
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto win vista

:next
ver | findstr "6.1"
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto next1
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto win7

:next1
ver | findstr "6.2" > nul
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto next2
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto win8

:next2
ver | findstr "6.3" > nul
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto next3
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto win8.1

:next3
ver | findstr "6.3" > nul
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto next4
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto win8.1

:next4
ver | findstr "10.0" > nul
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto other
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto win10

:xp
echo XP
goto :eof

:win vista
echo Vista
goto :eof

:win7
echo Win7
goto :eof

:win8
echo Win8
goto :eof

:win8.1
echo Win8.1
goto :eof

:win10
echo Win10
goto :eof

:other
echo Early Win
goto :eof
```